# Don't create snapshot for Rds DbInstance on stack deletion in CloudFormation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have created AWS::RDS::DBInstance using cloudformation and when I'm deleting the cloudformation stack its creating a snapshot for this DbInstance, I don't want to create that snapshot, that is I want to enable/disable skipFinalSnapshot flag based on my requirement, how to use that in cloudformation stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you use [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) for that:

> The default policy is **Snapshot** for [] AWS::RDS::DBInstance

If you don't want a snapshot, you can set your `DeletionPolicy` to `Delete` for your `DBInstance`. For example:

```
  MyDbInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
       # rest of db properties
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can set a deletion policy for your DB instance to control how AWS CloudFormation handles the instance when the stack is deleted. For Amazon RDS DB instances, you can choose to retain the instance, to delete the instance, or to create a snapshot of the instance. The default AWS CloudFormation behavior depends on the DBClusterIdentifier property:
>
> For AWS::RDS::DBInstance resources that don't specify the DBClusterIdentifier property, AWS CloudFormation saves a snapshot of the DB instance.
>
> For AWS::RDS::DBInstance resources that do specify the DBClusterIdentifier property, AWS CloudFormation deletes the DB instance.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html)